# why sqlite returns row counts of while Join

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

sqlite returns row count while executing this query

```
SELECT sum(s.Card_10) ,sum(p.Card_10) FROM Sales_Table s ,  Purchase_Table p
```

**ANSWER**
is sum(s.Card_10) 4 and sum(card_10) is 40

but if any execute these queries separately it reruns correct answer

```
Select sum(Card_10) from sales_table
```

**Answer**
1
and

```
Select sum(Card_10) from Purchase_table
```

**Answer**

40

why the error happen in such type of JOINS ?

Comment: Don't use commas in the `FROM` clause.  It creates the Cartesian product of the two tables.  If that is what you intend, then be explicit and use `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: cross join also retuns same answer here i just dump data only

Comment: SELECT sum(s.Card_10) ,sum(p.Card_10) FROM Sales_Table s CROSS JOIN   Purchase_Table p      ----------- same 4  and 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query

```
SELECT sum(s.Card_10) ,sum(p.Card_10) FROM Sales_Table s ,  Purchase_Table p
```

a `cross join` of `sales_table` and `purchase_table` would be performed. So if `sales_table` has `1` row with `card_10` column value of 1 and `purchase_table` has `4` rows with different values of `card_10` that sum up to 40.

So the `cross join` (with some dummy data) would look like

```
s.card_10   p.card_10
  1            5
  1            10
  1            8
  1            17
```

Hence you get the incorrect result.

One way of getting the correct counts in a single query is to use `union`.

```
select sum(Card_10) from sales_table 
union all
select sum(Card_10) from Purachase_table
```

or

```
select max(fromsalestable) as fromsalestable, max(frompurchasetable) as frompurchasetable 
from
(
select sum(Card_10) as fromsalestable, null as frompurchasetable from sales_table 
union all
select null, sum(Card_10) from Purachase_table
) t
```

Comment: (Y) Yppp Budddyyy THxx